# MYSQL SUBSTRING_INDEX / CONVERT / IF clause

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a table with something like this.

```
abc-cde-0001222
abc-cde-0001223
abc-ced-0001224
cde-efg-0003001
ced-efg-0003002
ced-efg-0003008
```

I wish to select `abc-cde-0001222, abc-ced-0001224`

```
        also cde-efg-0003001 , cde-efg-0003002

             ced-efg-0003008  , ""
```

See, I need to obtain 1st and last values of a range. If the particular value is only one item (not in a range) I want it to select as the 1st value and a null value.

So far I have only a Idea of using `IF` and `increment operator` (If this is possible). I can do the formatting and obtain the Int value using

```
SELECT field, CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field,'-',-1), UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS num
FROM table
ORDER BY num;
```

Please could you give me a hand... 
Lot appreciated

Comment: Currently I'm obtaining all the values and do the formatting in java. But it is very slow. So I thought that if there is a possibility to get only the data I need, it would be increasing the performance. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @kocko 
I have updated the question. Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: "could you give me a hand..." No thank you. I like my hands.

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson seems I could use your hand at this moment ;)
(thanks for reading)

Comment: Why does `ced-efg-0003002` appear as part of a range and also by itself?

Comment: so sorry @JimGarrison It was my mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pain in MySQL.  But, it is possible.  The logic is to find where a sequence starts.  You can do this with a correlated subquery and some arithmetic.  Then you want a cumulative sum of the starts.  This is harder, because it requires doing a correlated subquery on the correlated subquery.

First, to set the `NullIfStart` variable:

```
select t.*,
       (select 0
        from t t2
        where left(t2.field, 8) = left(t.field, 8) and
              t2.field < t.field and
              right(t2.field, 7) + 0 = right(t.field, 7) + 0 - 1
       ) as NullIfStart
from t;
```

This gets the cumulative sum, which can be used as a grouping field:

```
select t.*
       (select sum(NullIfStart is null)
        from (select t1.*,
                     (select 0
                      from t t2
                      where left(t2.field, 8) = left(t1.field, 8) and
                            t2.field < t1.field and
                            right(t2.field, 7) + 0 = right(t1.field, 7) + 0 - 1
                     ) as NullIfStart
               from t t1
              ) tnis
         where right(tnis.field, 7) = right(t.field, 7) and
               tnis.field <= t.field
        ) grp
from t;
```

The final solution is to do the aggregation:

```
select min(field),
       (case when max(field <> min(field) then max(field) end)
from (select t.*
             (select sum(NullIfStart is null)
              from (select t1.*,
                           (select 0
                            from t t2
                            where left(t2.field, 8) = left(t1.field, 8) and
                                  t2.field < t1.field and
                                  right(t2.field, 7) + 0 = right(t1.field, 7) + 0 - 1
                           ) as NullIfStart
                     from t t1
                    ) tnis
               where left(tnis.field, 8) = left(t.field, 8) and
                     tnis.field <= t.field
              ) grp
      from t
     ) s
group by left(s.field, 8), grp;
```

Comment: oh pretty complicated for me. Please give me sometime to comprehend your answer. I'm so grateful for this @Gordon Linoff

Comment: Performance-wise is this better than getting all the values and format using java?

Comment: @shan . . . I don't know.  It quite possible that returning the results in sorted order and doing the logic in java would be faster.  Actually, it might be possible to do the same thing with variables in MySQL, but I wasn't thinking along that path.

Comment: It is a somewhat big database and some times this queries may return 1000+ results.

Comment: @shan . . . That is not a big database.  Processing 1000 results in java is probably pretty fast.  If this might grow to hundreds of thousands, then I would start to worry, particularly about memory usage on the application side.

Comment: My logic in java is loop in incrementing a value by 1 and check if it equals with the next values, and categorize the ranges to get 1st and last value. Is that the only way? May be there is a better way.

Comment: It is a webApp in Struts2. I feel struts is a pain. But I'm too late when I realize that.